# My 3 litre diesel patrol revs increase from 750 to 1100 when I idle after a drive what would be the problem please

Tags: diesel

What would cause my 3 litre diesel to increase revs from 750 to 1100 when idling after a drive

Comment: Could you be more specific about *when* it happens? Does it happen when you are waiting for a traffic light to turn green? Does it happen when you put the car in Neutral or Park?

Comment: Thanks it happens when put in park after a few seconds and when waiting at traffic lights.